# Altering TextBox value before binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Given a simple bound `TextBox` like below, is there a way to alter the string before / as it's bound?

I'm binding the text to a RowFilter. so the string that works as "DATA LIKE '%exampletext%'" , I'd like for the user to only need to enter "exampletext" and then have the text wrapped in the other string before binding.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Filter" Text="{Binding example, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you handle this logic in the setter of the example property like you should?

Comment: I think what you want is called *a watermark.* Do a search for "wpf textbox watermark" and see if I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct place to handle this would be in the setter of the source (`example`) property.

If you don't want to do this for some reason, you might as well get rid of the binding and handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` in the view before you set the source property:

```
private void Filter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    string text = textBox.Text;
    //modify the text...
    string modifiedText = "...";
    //...and set the source property
    dynamic viewModel = textBox.DataContext;
    viewModel.example = modifiedText;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="Filter" TextChanged="Filter_TextChanged" />
```

There is no "before-source-property-is-set" event.

Another possible solution would be to use a value converter: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the complete string in your Viewmodel/code behind (DATA LIKE '%exampletext%) 
Then use some custom converters in your Textbox.Text binding to display only "exampletext" when the value is edited from your code (Convert method will be called) or write "DATA LIKE '%exampletext%" in your string value when the value is set from UI (ConvertBack method will be called)

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a Filter string in the viewmodel worked, and then altering it when it's set works.

```
    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _Filter; }
        set {

            MainVM.Modules.AllModules[0].Vwr.Table.dv.RowFilter = "PN LIKE '%" + _Filter + "%'";
            _Filter = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Filter)); }
    }
    private string _Filter = "";
```

Comment: sorry about that, came back to the question with a solution. I didn't read through the answers with a lot of focus.